# Calculating Covariance missing understanding for one step

Tags: algebra-precalculus, covariance

I am following [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Covariance)

once I get to this point

[image]

I don't understand the transition/calculation to get `-0.01`

I mean to me that equals `0.00` so what have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand why you are confused. It seems to me that first they calculate $\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 (x_i-x_{\mathrm{avg}})$ which is obviously zero, but due to rounding errors on $x_{\mathrm{avg}}$, they end up with -0.01. Similarly, due to rounding errors on $y_{\mathrm{avg}}$ they end up by saying that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 (y_i-y_{\mathrm{avg}})$ is 0.04. These two numbers are then multiplied and also multiplied by $1/8$. But this would be
$$
\frac18\Big(\sum_{i=1}^9(x_i-x_{\mathrm{avg}})\Big)\Big(\sum_{i=1}^9 (y_i-y_{\mathrm{avg}})\Big)
$$
which is *not* the formula for the (sample) covariance. The formula for the covariance is
$$
\frac18\sum_{i=1}^9(x_i-x_{\mathrm{avg}})(y_i-y_{\mathrm{avg}})
$$
which they correctly write at the top. Using this formula we would end up with -8.0694 approximately.

Comment: I don't quite understand the *rounding errors* part.. Would you mind elaborating a bit please? Do you mean like for X the average would be `44/9` which is `4.888888888888889` but they do `4.89` instead? Is that the source for the rounding error?

Comment: Yes exactly and as consequence they get $\sum_{i=1}^9 (x_i-x_{\mathrm{avg}})=-0.01$ which is obviously wrong since $\sum_{i=1}^9 (x_i-x_{\mathrm{avg}})=0$ always. But the important message is that they use a different formula than the covariance formula.